# angular2 [style.color] not working properly

Tags: angular, binding

I am trying to use a style binding in angular 2 but somehow I missed a part that causes it not working. The intention is to have the default text grey and when the user clicks on it (code not made yet) it changes to deeppink. But when testing the style property it doesn't seem to work.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: "like",
    template:  `
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" [style.color]="color ? 'grey' : 'deeppink'" style="font-size: 100px;"></i>
    `
})

export class LikeComponent {
    count: number = 10;
    color: true;

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just tested this and this works fine:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: 'like',
    template: `
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" [style.color]="color ? 'grey' : 'deeppink'" style="font-size: 100px;"></i>
        <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    `
})

export class LikeComponent {
    count: number = 10;
    color: boolean = true;
    toggle() {
        this.color = !this.color;
    }
}
```

pay attention to the

```
color: boolean = true;
```

instead of

```
color: true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
color: true;
```

to

```
color = true;
```

or

```
color: boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the component where you declare and set color. If you change it to the following it should work:

```
color:boolean = true;
```